# Problems with external hard disk

Tags: debian, hard-disk, buffer, data

I can't overcome a problem I have with my hard disk! I don't know if it is the right section, but the problem I have started suddenly while I was copying files on Debian.

The problem is that my external Seagate hard disk is not accessible in any way... I tried to connect it to a Windows computer too, but I always have the same problem...

So I tried to execute some commands on Debian:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FEE5A68A-D30E-49D6-ADBD-79D7FE3FEEDA

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 961667071 960616448 458,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  961667072 976771071  15104000   7,2G Linux swap
```

Now, what is strange is that if the disk is connected (it is on `/dev/sdb`) the command prints the output, stops for a while and ends, while if the disk is not connected it shows the output and stops immediately. Anyway, my device is not in the list.

I tried with `lsusb`, and the disk is shown, and with `lsscsi`. The disk is shown even in this situation.

I tried `dmesg | grep sdb` and this is part of the output:

```
# dmesg | grep sdb
[15564.910834] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[15565.020720] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[15565.020757] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[15565.020764] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[15565.020771] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 00
[15565.020777] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 4
[15565.020787] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 4, async page read
[15565.130678] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[15565.130700] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[15565.130706] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[15565.130715] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 01 00
[15565.130724] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 5
[15565.130737] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 5, async page read
[15565.240859] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[15565.240898] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[15565.240904] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[15565.240912] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 00
[15565.240917] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 6
[15565.240927] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 6, async page read
[15565.351140] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[15565.351180] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[15565.351186] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[15565.351193] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 01 00
[15565.351199] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 7
[15565.351209] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7, async page read
[15565.461412] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[15565.461443] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[15565.461450] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[15565.461457] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[15565.461463] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[15565.461472] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[15565.570662] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[15565.570701] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[15565.570707] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[15565.570714] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[15565.570720] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 1
[15565.570730] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, async page read
```

Then, I tried with:

```
# sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sdb
e2fsck: Errore di input/output nell'aprire /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: 
The super-blocco could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
file system.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
file system (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the super-blocco
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate super-blocco:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

But, I always get errors when I follow the suggestions... (super-blocco = superblock).

Windows detects the disk and it installs the drivers, showing it in the Device List and in the Disk Management (as a non allocated and not initialized disk). If I try to initialize the disk it gives me a cyclic redundancy check error.

If i try with `chkdsk` on Windows it doesn't work, because it doesn't detect the disk.

The strange thing is that when I inserted the disk for the first time using Debian it detected it immediately!

Please give me an hand, it is days I am facing the problem without reaching a solution!

Comment: What are you looking to do?  The disk is bad...

Comment: I would like to recover my data, if possible

Comment: *You* can't recover any data. A specialized service might but that's expensive and not guaranteed. The fee however must always be paid and before they start the recovery attempt. Don't waste your time and money. Next time make sure to have proper backups.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that the electronics and interface for your hard drive are likely working fine, but there's something wrong with the physical part (the rotating platters/heads.) If the interface or electronics themselves weren't working, you wouldn't be able to detect the drive at all. When the drive is asked to access the disk, it retries several times if it detects an error, which is why you are getting long delays when attempting to read data.

You *might* be able to recover some data using a recovery tool like [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), but it depends on the drive being readable. If the drive itself is unable to read the disk, no amount of software is going to help you get the data off the drive: you'll need to take it to a disk-recovery service.

Comment: Thank you! The disk cannot be read and I thought it was a problem linked to the USB cable maybe. I will wait for some time and try to recover my data in other ways!